# Deletar linhas duplicadas com condicionais postgresql

Tags: postgresql, trigger

Meu código pega informações da internet e insere no banco de dados, entretanto, ele insere uma mesma informação mais de uma vez por dia.

Eu preciso deixar apenas 1 informação do registro por dia, ou seja, cada dia que o programa rodar, ele vai inserir apenas 1 vez o registro no BD.

Exemplo:

```
    data     |  seller_id  |  
'2017-03-14' |   12345678  |
'2017-03-15' |   12345678  |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie uma unique key na chave que não quer que se repita , um erro ocorrerá se um insert a tentar duplicar , trate o erro na aplicação

Exemplo

```
ALTER TABLE distributors ADD CONSTRAINT dist_id_zipcode_key UNIQUE (dist_id, zipcode);
```

Fonte : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html

Comment: O problema de criar unique key na data é que mais de um id será inserido por dia, então eu nao posso colocar data como unique key. Mas nao posso colocar o id tambem, porque a cada dia será adicionada um novo dado desse mesmo id. A tabela ficaria com varios ids e datas:

    data          |     seller_id   |  
'2017-03-14' |   12345678  |
'2017-03-15' |   12345678  |
'2017-03-14' |   87654321  |
'2017-03-15' |   87654321  |

Comment: Falei de uma UNIQUE KEY composta por (data | seller_id) , se não for isto não entendi o problema , me desculpe.

Comment: Ah sim, agora entendi Motta. Você tem razão! Obrigado pela força, vou tentar aqui